# What to replace with deprecated `DefaultHttpAsyncClient`?

Tags: java, deprecation-warning, apache-httpasyncclient

I'm modifying a existing project but I see that `DefaultAsyncHttpClient` is deprecated. What to replace the deprecated one?

```
        HttpAsyncClient httpclient;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            // TODO: deprecated ??
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpAsyncClient();
            httpclient.start();
        try {
           
            // some code

            httpclient.shutdown();
        }
        
        catch(Exception e) {
         
        }
        }
```

`.start()` i cant fetch that method either and neither i can fetch `.shutdown` method.

Thank for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CloseableHttpAsyncClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.1.x/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchange.java) , `close` instead of `shutdown`

> ```
> CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
>    try {
>        httpclient.start();
>        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/get");
>        Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(request, null);
>        HttpResponse response = future.get();
>        System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
>        System.out.println("Shutting down");
>    } finally {
>        httpclient.close();
>    }
> ```